# wget without keeping the cache

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, wget

I'm trying to run a remote bash script hosted on github:

```
wget -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xxxxx/script.sh
```

All works good, no problems

But when I update the script above, and I run the same command, it processes the old script

I tried with `--no-cache`, `--delete-after`, without success

How to get a fresh copy of the wget everytime?

Comment: Specifying an explicit commit id, e.g. `59525a08` instead of say the branch name, e.g. `dev`, should negate the cache.

Comment: In my experience, sometimes GitHub Pages and/or the RAW CDN get "stuck" and you can try to make a small change in your code and commit to force the newest version to regenerate again... this is the only solution I've found, besides what @Asclepius mentioned above re: `wget` a specific commit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`raw.githubusercontent.com` is using a CDN, as you can inspect by doing:

```
$ dig raw.githubusercontent.com +short
github.map.fastly.net.
1.2.3.4
```

so, if that CDN is enforcing a TTL-based caching (and it seems so, by checking the `Cache-Control` header of 300 seconds), you are stuck with it.
As you saw asking with `--no-cache` doesn't do anything because that's the way these are designed to prevent abuses.

You may bypass it in many *hacky* ways, which I won't list, but you are basically trying to circumvent a policy set forth by github and I would advise against. Moreover a method which works today might not work programmatically tomorrow or in subsequent calls.

So.. Just wait for the TTL to expire and get the new copy.

You may write a script which polls every x-seconds (don't make it too fast though) and wait until you see `X-Cache: MISS` - that will tell you that you got a new copy. Or that checks the `ETag` for changes.

Or you may check if github provides you with an API to invalidate your own code, or a way to call files with the latest commit, like: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xxxxx/script.sh?commit=12345

Comment: thanks for a very good answer. but I was wondering: "You may bypass it in many hacky ways"... Could you share couple of "ways" to do it ?